# Rendering Dynamic asp.net webpage into string invoked from another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, rendering, placeholder

The question basically drill's down to these two C# 2.0, ASP.NET 2.0 webpages.

```
viewtemplate.aspx

generatetemplate.aspx
```

**Purpose of these:**

`viewtemplate.aspx` - Displays Email template defined in 'generatetemplate.aspx', with client assigned data pulled from database

`generatetemplate.aspx` - Is the actual page that contains place holders for client to put data.
[i named it so because that's the file i will be generating email to be sent from]

**Requirement:**

> I will be requesting the generatetemplate.aspx from viewtemplate.aspx

, get the rendered output of generatetemplate.aspx and then send that output as email to the recipients.
It is the rendering part which i don't know how to do.

**Note:**

I will be calling `generatetemplate.aspx` from `viewtemplate.aspx` with query string so that `generatetemplate.aspx` will Pull value from database and then render rather than rendering with default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wish to get the rendered HTML output of running the page? You can download it from an HTTP request like a browser would with the WebClient class.

```
string generated = new WebClient().DownloadString("generatetemplate.aspx?myparams=params");
```

"generated" will then contain rendered output that you can do whatever you like with.

Comment: You're welcome. I was hoping the syntax was correct...I typed it on my phone from the bathroom. Just thought you should know.

Comment: @Jordon Bathroom's are place where people are getting to invent new things and code right

Answer (score 0):

if I got question right, this is looks dodgy a bit.
I've used XSL + XML for such case. So you just prepare data in XML format, than applying XSL layout and thats it.

Comment: @sil Even though i accepted a answer, you deserve a up vote for showing something easy.do you have a blog or something,where you could post some example. Also do email clients read xml, xslt properly ?